# Salvaging a failing SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have an old 512GB Crucial M4 that failed on me (~300 bad sectors in accessible space w/ repeatable read errors, reallocation failures and significant data loss). Presumably all the mandatory OP space is full of bad blocks (reallocated sector count capped at 4096, and I don't recall pending sector count).

I don't really like throwing things away and I'd like to see how far I can stretch the drive as (unreliable) external storage before I ditch it on the side of the highway and hitch-hike home.

I have therefore performed the following operations on the drive in an attempt to squeeze some more life out of it:

1. Secure erase, then
2. TRIM whole device
3. Create new MBR and new NTFS partition with 100GB extra unallocated space left at end of drive for additional OP (the drive has something like ~50GB mandatory OP to begin with).

Since doing this, the drive has been behaving reasonably well with no additional errors.

My question is: Is this a reasonable salvage procedure? Can I continue to squeeze life out of this drive as it continues to fail by increasing over-provisioning space until the drive's functioning capacity is too small to be useful?

Edit: I can *kind* of see why this is being flagged as opinion-based, that wasn't my intention. So, more specifically, the question is: **In the face of high reallocation counts and repeatable read errors (implying saturation of reserve space), will increasing the amount over over-provisioned space allow the drive to continue functioning reasonably well until the over-provisioned space is eventually all used up as well (if that ever happens)?**

Comment: Did you take a look at [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) ?

Comment: `before I ditch it on the side of the highway` at least ditch it on one of the available recycling centers in your town. *rhetorical*

Answer (score 2):

SSD's are usually reliable and do not crash easily. According to your claim that your SDD is working fine now, I would recommend that you use your SSD as you are using now and I don't think it would crash now. If I were you, I would continue using the SSD as normal like nothing happened.  Anyways keep a backup of your data.( although there is no need to)

Comment: Thanks. Well I actually did suffer a bit of data loss when this drive went bad (and was equally surprised at its failure). Since the reallocation count is so high (and the other SMART statistics don't look so hot either) I'm not going to trust it for a main drive. I already installed a replacement (1TB Samsung 840 EVO, a big upgrade to the m4 anyways), and I back up nightly to a nas (there is *always* a need to back up your data :) ).